# stop ajax function setinterval redirect in controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**ajax call**

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
var timeOutID =0;
var checkScore =  function ()
  {
$.ajax({
  url: "<?php echo 'http://127.0.0.1/ProgVsProg/main/checkScore'?>",
  success:function(response){
    if(response){
       $('#maincontent1').html(response);
     timeOutID = setTimeout(checkScore, 3000);
      } 
    else
      {
     clearTimeout(timeOutID); 
    }
  }
});
}
timeOutID = setTimeout(checkScore,1000);
```

**controller**

```
    public function checkScore(){
    $id = $this->session->userdata('userID');
    $battleID = $this->lawmodel->getBattle($id);
        foreach($battleID as $row){
            $Rscore = $row->requestedScore;
            $Cscore = $row->challengerScore;
            if($Cscore=="1"){
                $rID = $this->lawmodel->getID($row->challengerID);
                redirect('main/secondRound');
                }
        else if($Rscore == '1'){
        $cID =$this->lawmodel->getID($row->requestedID);    
        redirect('main/secondRound');   
        }           
    }
}
```

**secondRound Controller**

```
public function secondRound(){
    $category = 'medium';
    $data['results'] = $this->lawmodel->roundTwoQuestion($category);
    $data['content'] = 'battlePage';
    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
    {
        $this->load->view('includes/template2',$data);
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('main/restricted');
    }
}
```

my problem is how can i stop the execution of the ajax call using setTimeout() since it get from the controller that redirects to another controller...and my other problem is ajax function will execute directly even it not yet met the condition in the controller. it will return to blank page..

PLSS help!! im new in ajax..:(

Comment: please indent (and normalize) your code... Seriously, that's your 2014 resolution.

Comment: And don't use tabs at SO

Comment: I see timeOutID,timeOutIDs and checkScores,checkScoresD

Comment: I see checkScore and checkScores

Comment: sorry..my bad..

all clear now..@.@

Comment: May this url may help you check it [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938989/header-wont-redirect-when-passedthrough-ajax]