# Header wont redirect when passedthrough ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Not sure if this is possible but I have a page that submits a form with AJAX and if it meets certain conditions it should automatically take the user to another page. NOTHING is outputted before the header tag its just a bunch of conditions.

Problem: Header redirect not working...

**AJAX**

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: '_ajax/add.php',
     data: $('form').serialize(),
     success: function (data) {
       $("input").val('Company Name');
       $("form").hide();
       getInfo();
     }
   });
});
```

**add.php**

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$id = $row['id'];
header("Location: http://localhost/manage/card.php?id=$id");
```

Comment: Nope, that won't work.  You'll need to return a redirect parameter via ajax, and have the javascript do the redirect.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indicate in the question that under **certain conditions**, you want a redirect.

To do that, you would want to alter your javascript to contain an if condition, and to watch for certain responses.

I would recommend modifying your responses to be json, so that you can pass back different information (such as a success status, as well as a redirect url, or other information you might want).

```
 $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: '_ajax/add.php',
     data: $('form').serialize(),
     success: function (data) {
       var response = $.parseJSON(data);
       if (response.redirect) {
           window.location = response.redirect_url;
       } else {
           $("input").val('Company Name');
           $("form").hide();
           getInfo();
       }
     }
   });
});
```

As for your add.php file, you'll want to change this to be something more like so:

```
$json = array(
    'redirect' => 0,
    'url'      => '',
}

if (...condition for redirect...) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $id = $row['id'];
    $json['redirect'] = 1;
    $json['redirect_url'] = "Location: http://localhost/manage/card.php?id=$id";
}
echo json_encode($json);
die();
```

Comment: this seems like the best solution, however i am having a little difficulty sorting out a couple things to get it working. Ill let you know if i can sort it out

Comment: Im getting an unexpected token error with the .parseJSON(data) and when i eliminate the parse it just returns the location as a string any thoughts on this error? I can post code with reques

Comment: @user934902 - it sounds like you aren't using `json_encode()`.  If you don't, then the parseJSON will throw errors.

Answer (score 3):

Headers can only be modified before any body is sent to the browser (hence the names header/body).  Since you have AJAX sent to the browser, you can't modify the headers any more.  However, you can have the `add.php` script called via AJAX return the `$id` parameter. Then that parameter can be used in JavaScript to redirect the page: `window.location = 'http://localhost/manage/card.php?id=' + id`.

More info on PHP `header()`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

**AJAX**

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: '_ajax/add.php',
     data: $('form').serialize(),
     success: function (data) {
       window.location = 'http://localhost/manage/card.php?id=' + data;
     }
   });
});
```

**add.php**

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$id = $row['id'];
echo $id;
exit;
```

Comment: it is a period(.) in php and that isn't the issue here.

Comment: @AshleyMedway if you can see the `+ id` I use is in JavaScript.  Hence `window.location =`.

Comment: Apollogies but i still think the OP want his ajax call to run via the add.php and return a result

Comment: The problem is the AJAX can't call a `header()` since output has already been given.  I'm suggesting to still use the AJAX call to return the `$id`, and use the parameter to do a redirect in pure JavaScript.

Comment: all i want to do is redirect the user to another page after the add.php has run, obviously header() is not the solution now, trying to pass the data back and redirect on AJAX success as suggested

Comment: @SamSullivan Why can the ajax request not call header?! the ajax request is treated as a new request without a body

Comment: @SamSullivan With the edits you have made it is now a valid solution +1

Comment: @user934902 see my examples.  @Ashley Medway `header()` will work..but it will redirect the `add.php` request, and the AJAX request will receive the redirect's data (instead of redirecting the user's page).

Comment: yup, thanks almost had exactly what you had with advice from your first answer without the edit, but the edit was good clarification. Thank you!

Comment: @SamSullivan yes this is how ajax is intended to work, i believe we should keep the php header() and return the entire result back to the browser rather than using location redirect. but each to their own :)

Comment: @user934902 Take an array and JSON encode it.  `echo json_encode($array)`.  Then in the AJAX.success callback function, `data` will be an object.  So if `$array = array('test' => 'abc', 'id' => 123);` then `data.test = 'abc'; data.id = 123;`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a miss understanding of how AJAX works. [Introduction to Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp).
The reason why your redirect appears not to working is because an Ajax call doesn't directly affect your browser. It's a behind the scenes call.

To get the data out from the AJAX call you need to do something with the returned data.

```
success: function (data) {
  $("input").val('Company Name');
  $("form").hide();

  //You need to do something with data here.
  $("#myDiv").html(data); //This would update a div with the id myDiv with the response from the ajax call.

  getInfo();
}
```